# Libgdx Memory size for variable type

Tags: java, android, memory, int, libgdx

Once I read the answer on internet (could be in Stack Overflow as well, I can't remember) showing all memory usage for each variable type in LibGdx , such as `int`, `float`, `Boolean`, and etc. however, I can't find it anymore. Can you please point me to that right direction?

In additional, as everyone suggested on the internet that memory usage should be kept to the minimal for Android apps, is there any way that I can use `Small Int` or `Tiny Int` (instead of of using `int`) since my variable are really small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the size of any object you can have a look at [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object).

If you do not need a whole `int` (32 bit) you can use `short` (16 bit) or even `byte` (8 bit).